# Pixel Formats supported Android Things 0.7 DP

Tags: android, image, android-camera2, android-things, pixelformat

I was running an app in Android Things (Raspberry Pi 3) DP 0.6.1 using the Camera 2 Api and getting images with format PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 successfully. Now I updated the Operating system to version DP 0.7 and greater resolutions are supported in ImageFormat but now I'm getting Null for resolutions in PixelFormat.RGBA_8888.
(1) Isn't PixelFormat going to be supported any more?
Moreover, I tried to switch to other pixel format (RGB_888) and the app crashes in line imageReader.aquireLatestImage() with this error: < producer output buffer format doesn't match the image reader's configured buffer format>
(2) In order to get high frame rate (frames per second) at high resolutions which would be the better formats to use?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of what you're doing now?

Comment: please post the code scratch.